# JS Pop Up window

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Basically I just want to click on the link an a new window should open. But the window does open in a new tab. 
Not sure why

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 12px;" onclick="popupwindow(this.href, 'Redirect to')"><b>Link</b></a>
```

The JS: [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vicR/63Xu9/3/)

Comment: And if I said "works for me"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open url in new tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow Steps :-

```
1. In html write return false to avoid default event default behaviour
2. From javascript return false
3. Check for popup blocker
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function popupwindow(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (newwindow == null || typeof(newwindow)=='undefined') {  
        alert('Please disable your pop-up blocker and click the "Open" link again.'); 
    } 
    else {  
        newwindow.focus();
    }
    return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popupwindow(this.href)"
    >Link to popup</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot be controlled, it's entirely at the discretion of the user-agent.